# what are differences of the COM port R/W function between Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, winapi, file-io, serial-port, linux-device-driver

I wrote both the COM port read and write under Windows and Linux, and I use same hardware , which linked to my HOST.

In Linux, I use following code to achieve COM port write from HOST to my hardware, `write` is Linux api:

```
DWORD l1_SerWrite(const BYTE *pbData, DWORD dwLen) {
  DWORD dwRet = write(g_hDevice, pbData, dwLen);
  tcdrain(g_hDevice);
  return dwRet;
}
```

In Windows, I use below codes, `WriteFile` is winapi:

```
DWORD l1_SerWrite(const BYTE *pbData, DWORD iLen) {
  DWORD dwNumBytesWritten;
  WriteFile(g_hPort, pbData, iLen, &dwNumBytesWritten, NULL);
  return dwNumBytesWritten;
}
```

During the test of my program, I found in windows, I can always write data to my hardware, but under Linux, it always fail, but sometimes it can write data to my hardware. I also use scope to catch the waveform from BUS and I can see both under Windows and Linux, the data already been send out by HOST.

I also did one test, if I use pure 9-pin COM cable, windows has no problem, but Linux will fail to get data some times, but if I use USB2Serial cable, Linux can work with my HOST program.

UPDATE:

In Linux, before open the COM port, I did following set:

```
BOOL l1_OpenCOM(char *szCOM, DWORD nxBaud, BOOL fHwFlowCtrl) {
struct termios settings;

  strcpy(g_szCOMPort, szCOM);

  g_hDevice = open(g_szCOMPort, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

  if (g_hDevice < 0) {
    g_hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    return FALSE;
  }

  memset(&settings, 0, sizeof(settings));
  settings.c_cflag = CS8 | CREAD | CLOCAL | HUPCL;
  if (fHwFlowCtrl) {//during the data transition, the fHwFlowCtrl is FALSE
    settings.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;
  }

  if (tcsetattr(g_hDevice, TCSANOW, &settings) != 0) {
    close(g_hDevice);
    return FALSE;
  }

  if (l1_ChangeBaud(nxBaud) == FALSE) {
    close( g_hDevice );
    return FALSE;
  }

  if (l1_SetTimeouts() == FALSE) {
    close( g_hDevice );
    return FALSE;
  }

  l1_PurgeCOM();

  return TRUE;
}
```

I'm NOT sure these settings are enough.

Comment: Maybe different hand-shaking protocols? E.g. Linux may be configured by default to use CTS/RTS?

Comment: You can use a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) before attempting the `read(2)` or `write(2)`. Also `DWORD` is not a Linux datatype. `write(2)` returns an `ssize_t`. Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: @Jonathan Potter, but in Linux it NOT every time fail, some time it can pass some data, like 10 packages, some time, can NOT pass every package, sometimes it can pass whole data package

Comment: If the CTS/RTS lines aren't connected they may be floating around and so occasionally the handshaking will "appear" to work. This would explain why the USB adapter works, since that probably grounds the lines.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, but I saw from oscilloscope, the data already send out from my Linux HOST, but my device NOT get that or NOT get whole data, meanwhile, if I use usb2serial cable, my hardware has no problem to get whole data under Linux

Comment: @Jonathan Potter, can I understand you point like: I should use HW flow control, otherwise, I need totally disable these RTS/CTS line?

Comment: If my theory is right it may just be a matter of setting the comm port parameters in Linux to disable hardware handshaking. I wouldn't know how to do that though!

Comment: @Jonathan Potter, but why under windows it has no problem? because windows disable those line? I will post more code on windows

Comment: See e.g. http://www.zeitronix.com/zdl/zdl_setup_determine_com_port.shtml - the com port may be set with flow control disabled by default.